# visual basic do while input

Tags: vb.net, input, while-loop, do-while

I have to make a "Do - while" input from a TextBox in Visual Basic. I mean I get some value for the amount of the numbers the user should type, and then I have to get this quantity of numbers from a textbox. I suppose the event is on TextBox1_KeyPress() but then the event is true even when I type in 0 for example and this way I won't be able to write the whole number, but the first digit. I want to be able to type in the whole number and then when I press Enter the value from the txtBox goes in some variable and cleans itself to write the next one.
Anyone who has any ideas? I'm really new in VB, sorry :(

Comment: what's do-while for ?

Comment: I have a TxtBox where I have to type the amount of numbers i'll calculate, for example the Sum of those numbers. Then i have to get this amount and type as many numbers as the amount is. In C/C++/C# i do this with do - while, but i have to do this in VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `key_press`. use `key_up`. in event args you will find `keycode`. for `enter` the code is 13. so when keycode = 13, extract textbox1.text to a variable. then clear the text box like textbox1.text = "". when ever you do this, increment a member variable by one. by that variable you will know how many values have been entered.